# Visual Studio 2019 does not allow code change while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've recently switched from Visual Studio 2017 to 2019 and I'm having an issue with changing the code after hitting a breakpoint (Debugging).

Even a small change, e.g. changing the value of a variable prevents the code from continuing and I always get the message:
***Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging.***

[Visual Studio 2019 Debugging settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3MgM.png)

Is this a bug of Visual Studio 2019 or is this an expected behavior? On VS2017 I was able to change large portion of the code and still I was able to continue executing the code without restarting the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full, up-to-date list of where edit and continue works, and doesn't work.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/EnC-Supported-Edits.md